# Unable to assign a gdb convenience variable to objective-c object

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode, debugging, gdb

Using gdb in xcode, I'm unable to assign an objective-c object to a convenience variable. Is there any way to do this or to set up a mechanism to accomplish the same thing?

```
(gdb) print-object [NSFileManager defaultManager]
<NSFileManager: 0x60033e0>
(gdb) print-object $_
Value can't be converted to integer.
(gdb) set $theManager=[NSFileManager defaultManager]
(gdb) print-object $theManager
Value can't be converted to integer.
```

Comment: I've moved your answer to an answer - I didn't spot it when I first came to this page!

Answer (score 0):

Just cast the object to `id`.

```
(gdb) set $mgr = (id)[NSFileManager defaultManager]
(gdb) print-object $mgr
<NSFileManager: 0x60033e0>
(gdb)
```